# Why does the gas constant R appear in heat capacities?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Often, expressions for the heat capacity of a gas include a term $R = \pu{8.314 J K-1 mol-1}$. For example, the constant-volume molar heat capacity of a monoatomic gas is

$$C_{v,m} = \frac{3}{2}R$$

Why is this factor of $R$ so ubiquitous?

Comment: What do you think, based on the derivation of kinetic gas theory?

Answer (score 5):

Temperature is just a form of energy and it would be more naturally expressed in energy units than in degrees. But because temperature is an older concept than (thermal) energy and very familiar to us, we keep using temperature. Just like with the exchange of foreign currency, there is a simple conversion factor to go from temperature to energy and that is the Boltzmann constant $k_\text{B}$, that is, if we consider the thermal energy of a single atom or molecule. When you consider a mole of particles, you need to multiply the Boltzmann constant with Avogadro's number $N_\text{A}$ to get the conversion factor. The product of $k_\text{B}$ and $N_\text{A}$ is the gas constant $R$.

A more thorough derivation comes from the equipartition theorem, which states that every degree of freedom contributes $\tfrac{1}{2}k_\text{B}T$ to the energy of a particle. Taking the derivative with respect to temperature of the resulting expression gives then a constant term containing the Boltzmann constant for a single particle (or the gas constant for a mole of particles).